# Apache ProxyPassReverse catching external redirects

Tags: apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy

What we want to do is use apache (2.4) as a reverse proxy to tomcat, we would like to use mod_proxy
I've put in the following configuration:

```
<Location /abc/>
    Require all granted
    ProxyPass ajp://10.10.10.10:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse /
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /  /abc/
</Location>
```

This all seems to function fine except for the issue that when we issue a redirect to a external site it seems to be caught by the ProxyPassReverse and redirected to our site. We do use redirects internally but I was expecting only redirects to 10.10.10.10 to be rewritten.

Also I'm a little unclear if our proxypassreverse needs the hostname:

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / https://%{SERVER_NAME}/abc/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to drop the

```
ProxyPassReverse /
```

and add:

```
Header edit Location ^https://myserver.net/(.*)$ https://myserver.net/abc/$1
```

I don't believe I need the

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / https://%{SERVER_NAME}/abc/
```